# Pub/Sub messages from snapshot not processed in a Dataflow streaming pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

We have a Dataflow consumming from a Pub/Sub and writing into bigquery in streaming. Due to a permits issue the pipeline got stuck and the messages were not consumed, we re-started the pipeline, save the unacked messages in a snapshot, replay the messages but they are discarded

- We fix the problem, re-deployed the pipeline with a new subscription to the topic and all the events are consumed in streaming without a problem
- For all the unacked messages accumulated (20M) in the first subscription, we created a snapshot
- This snapshot was then connected to the new subscription via the UI using Replay messages dialog
- In the metrics dashboard we see that the unacked messages spike to 20M and then they get consumed
  [subscription spike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZFbj.png)
- But then the events are not sent to BigQuery, checking inside dataflow job metrics we are able to see a spike in the Duplicate message count within the read from pubsub step
  [Dataflow Duplicate counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFFur.png)

The messages are < 3 days old, does anybody knows why this happen? Thanks in advance

The pipeline is using Apache Beam SDK 2.39.0 and python 3.9 with streming engine and v2 runner enable.

Comment: It simply gets stuck, no errors or anything? I'd look at the worker logs to make sure.

Comment: No errors in the worker, the only unusual thing is the spike in duplicate messages

Comment: @JesúsRojas Is there windowing implemented for this unbounded stream?  how frequently trigger fire the pcollection, and what is the lateness horizon configured?

Answer (score 0):

How long does it take for a Pub/Sub message to process, is it a long process?

In that case, Pub/Sub may redeliver messages, according to subscription configuration/delays. See [Subscription retry policy](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#subscription_retry_policy).

Dataflow can work-around that, as it acknowledges from the source after a successful shuffle. If you add a [GroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/GroupByKey.html) (or artificially, a  [Reshuffle](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Reshuffle.html)) transform, it may resolve source duplications.

More information at https://beam.apache.org/contribute/ptransform-style-guide/#performance